# Hyperledger-fabric v1.0.0 instantiate chaincode on kubernetes failed

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric

I was testing Hyperledger-fabic v1.0.0 with kubernetes. The fabic contains 2 orgs, 4 peers, 1 orderer, and a cli. The things goes well until I instantiates the chaincode in the cli. The peer's error message in the picture. It says missing image, but the image just create successful. What's the problem and how can I solve it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSbIm.png)
   peer's error message

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be found in the Hyperledger RocketChat on the [#fabric-kubernetes channel](https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-kubernetes?msg=v27L9igqJZRDW9wQz).

"you basically need the peer to surface its dynamic IP (thats what `AUTOADDRESS` does) and then tell the chaincode to basically ignore the x509 CN thats what `SERVERHOSTOVERRIDE` does
(and the other part is you need the peer pod to be privelged so it has the rights to drive the docker-api".

Basically, there's lots to be learned from following the discussion from that point.

Comment: Hi, christo4ferris. I saw the answer in the Hyperledger RocketChat. And I added AUTOADDRESS and SERVERHOSTOVERRIDE in my yaml file. But it seems not work .  My yaml file like this: -name: CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT value: "true", -name:CORE_PEER_TLS_SERVERHOSTOVERRIDE value: "$x509::CN". Is this true ? By the way, I changed the CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED  to false, so I think   CORE_PEER_TLS_SERVERHOSTOVERRIDE didn't work.

Comment: No, what you want to do is set CORE_PEER_TLS_SERVERHOSTOVERRIDE to the value of the server's x509 CN. You'll find that in that node's TLS certificate. Also, unsetting TLS_ENABLED will obviously not help this particular configuration (assume you want the traffic secured).